# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm getting the 150 error when attempting to run the following setup script.
Whats wrong?

serverPermissions seems to trigger the error but I'm not exactly sure why.
I think the foreign key constraints are all properly mapped as far as I can tell. I am probably missing something obvious.

```
-- Setup my members database
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mymembers;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mymembers;

/*
* The list of all members in the community
*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS members;
CREATE TABLE members
(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(30),
steamID3 INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

/*
* Lists all servers in operation
*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS servers;
CREATE TABLE servers
(
sid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
sname VARCHAR(30), -- name of server (short name)
PRIMARY KEY(sid)
);

/*
* Maps a member and a server together along with a flag. 
* Record (0, 12, 1, 0) indicates member 12 has flag 0 on server 1.
*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS serverPermissions;
CREATE TABLE serverPermissions
(
mid INT,
sid INT,
flagid INT,
PRIMARY KEY(mid, sid, flagid),
FOREIGN KEY (mid) REFERENCES members(id),
FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES servers(sid),
FOREIGN KEY (flagid) REFERENCES flags(id)
);

/*
* flags are used to give custom permissions to players.
* For example a record may be: (0, "VIP", "This play is very important")
*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS flags;
CREATE TABLE flags
(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(10),
description VARCHAR(100),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the order of table creation. You should create `flags` table before creating `serverPermissions`. See a [Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67223).

Comment: Oh my how embarrassing. I was making the database at 3AM so thats my excuse. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While adding foreign key constraints, both the tables should have storage type as InnoDb. Change the type for both tables from MyISAM to InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

This link (https://mariadb.org/mariadb-innodb-foreign-key-constraint-errors/) gives a quick snapshot of the engine types that support the foreign keys.

As far as I know, the following storage engines for MariaDB and/or MySQL support foreign keys:

```
InnoDB (both innodb_plugin and XtraDB)
PBXT (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-pbxt/)
SolidDB for MySQL (http://sourceforge.net/projects/soliddb/)
ScaleDB (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/scaledb/ and http://scaledb.com/pdfs/TechnicalOverview.pdf)
MySQL Cluster NDB 7.3 or later (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-cluster-ndb-innodb-engines.html)
```